# generating page link using asp-page tag in a solution that has multple projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I have one asp.net core project (Project A) with razor pages. I added a new module as a new project (Project B). Now the solution has two projects Project A and Project B. I added a reference to Project A in Project B so that I can access resources belongs to Project A.

Now users can login to the system and they can see the dashboard in Project A.I need to add menu link to the new module in Project B using 'asp-page' tag helper. Is it possible to generate link to a razor page in another project using asp-page tag helper? If not possible how can I set a link in razor page? I also tried to window.location.href in javascript but it always redirected to Project A's home page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, having separate web project means having them hosted on different URLs (in most cases) so you would have to either create your own tag helper that would recognize different projects and or just hardcore relative path of your URLs.

I would recommend storing web project A and B URLs in web.config so it is easier to update them once code gets pushed to different environment.

Comment: I need to publish it in same url .Is it possible ? @cycaHuH

Comment: It is if you will host it as a Virtual directory - in this case B will be a subfolder of A